# Identifying a input protection diode from a power supply by a photo

Tags: pcb, identification, circuit-protection, surge-protection, diode-clamp

block schematic is

[image: schematic].

And connector photograph is

[image].

and broken element is

[image].

It seems to be TVS (Transient Voltage Suppressors) diode. Maybe, %20 unidirectional. Because, there is a mini hole in the right. Approximately diameter 6mm and length 10mm. On the writing is 2082 B.

Anybody used it before? I don't find in Internet. What could be **DCL** and **SA**? What may be the abbreviation?

Comment: Maybe a [Z2082](http://www.x-on.com.au/MPN/Z2082)

Comment: SA might be "Surge Arrester".

Comment: @brhans, Z2082 I don't think. Because on the connector 310 VDC.

Comment: I found. http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/586960/OKAYA/B2082.html

Comment: Direct Current Limiter? Aka a fuse?